# Weird Behavior When Slicing a List in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, sklearn-pandas

I have some data in pandas that I want to use for named entity recognition. Sample of the data is below

```
text
['Angie', '’s', 'is', 'my', 'favorite', 'but', 'the', 'prices', 'at', 'little', 'Tonys', 'are', 'better', '.']

tags
['B-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

I ran `sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` on the data

```
# split data
train_texts, test_texts, train_tags, test_tags = train_test_split(dataset["text"].tolist(),
                                                                dataset["tags"].tolist(),
                                                                test_size=0.20,
                                                                random_state=15)
```

However, when I try to print the list it gives me some weird behavior, specifically, it counts the square brackets `[]` and quotes `''` around the text and tags as part of the test and tags. For example, when I write

```
print(train_texts[0][0:9], train_tags[0][0:9], sep='\n')

output
['Angie',
['B-ORG',
```

My question is, why is it counting the brackets and quote characters as part of the string? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `DataFrame` for declaration and performed the same task of splitting `train_texts and test_texts` and `train_tags and test_tags`. Kindly refer to a Solution Stated below. Then we will move ahead with the issue of `[]` and `''` in your scenario.

```
# Import all the important libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Store all String data into the 'data' variable
data = {
'text' : ['Angie', '’s', 'is', 'my', 'favorite', 'but', 'the', 'prices', 'at', 'little', 'Tonys', 'are', 'better', '.'],
'tags' : ['B-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'O', 'O', 'O']}

# Store above Initialized Data into DataFrame
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**NOTE:-** Always Print few Records of the `dataset` before moving ahead. Because it may happen sometimes that there was issue in your `dataset` which can deflect your expected result.

```
# Print a few records of 'dataset'
dataset

    text        tags
0   Angie       B-ORG
1   ’s          I-ORG
2   is          O
3   my          O
4   favorite    O
5   but         O
6   the         O
7   prices      O
8   at          O
9   little      B-ORG
10  Tonys       I-ORG
11  are         O
12  better      O
13  .           O
```

Now we can pursue the splitting part. I have used the same method which was mentioned in your question part.

```
# split data
train_texts, test_texts, train_tags, test_tags = train_test_split(
    dataset["text"].tolist(),
    dataset["tags"].tolist(),
    test_size=0.20,
    random_state=15)
```

So, after Splitting we can print a Sliced list of `train_texts and train_tags`

```
print(train_texts[0][0:9], train_tags[0][0:9], sep='\n')
```

`Output` of the above cell is stated below:-

```
favorite
O
```

As you can see, it was not printing any `[]` and `''` in Output.

**Your Question:-**

**Q.) Why is it counting the brackets and quote characters as part of the string? How can I fix it?**
A.) I don't know a proper reason behind this issue. But it may happen sometimes if your data haven't declared properly or due to any other declaration issue. But printing `dataset` before moving ahead is a great practice. Because you can identify the behavior of data from this method.

**Solution:-** Usage of `DataFrame` worked for me perfectly. You can use that.

Hope this Solution helps you. If you are still facing an issue kindly upload the full code. So, that we can find a solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
text
Angie ’s is my favorite but the prices at little Tonys are better.

tags
B-ORG I-ORG O O O O O O O B-ORG I-ORG O O O
```

It looks like you are trying to turn a string that is formatted to look like a list into a list.  It doesn't know any better so the brackets and apostrophes are going along for the ride.